# How to transform equivalent optimization problems

Tags: optimization

Can somebody either explain how to show the equivalence of the three alternative optimization problems in MPT (or point me to some literature)?

I am looking for the necessary "algebraic steps" if at all possible rather than the intuitive explanation so that I can apply the same principle to other optimization problems.

The three equivalent optimization problems I am thinking of are:

$
    \renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
    \newcommand{\mat}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
    \newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
$

$
    \begin{aligned}
    &\underset{\vec x}{\text{minimize}} && \vec x^T \mat\Sigma \vec x 
                                            \\
    &\text{subject to}                  && \vec1 \cdot \vec x = 1, \\
    &                                   && \vec\mu_{\vec x} \cdot \vec x \ge r_{min} \\\\
    \end{aligned}
$

$
    \begin{aligned}
    &\underset{\vec x}{\text{maximize}} && \vec\mu_{\vec x} \cdot \vec x \\
    &\text{subject to}                  && \vec1 \cdot \vec x = 1, \\
    &                                   && \vec x^T \mat\Sigma \vec x 
                                            \le \sigma_{max}^2\\\\
    \end{aligned}
$

$
    \begin{aligned}
    &\underset{\vec x}{\text{minimize}} && \vec x^T \mat\Sigma \vec x -\gamma \vec\mu_{\vec x} \cdot \vec x \\
    &\text{subject to}                  && \vec1 \cdot \vec x = 1, \\
    \end{aligned}
$